# Javascript variable values are not being changed inside loop

Tags: javascript

Hi i have a few global variables in javascript. I am changing those variables inside a loop depending on condition. The code is following

```
                      var isrun=true;
                  var isleft=false;
                  var isright=true;
                  var isup=false;
                  var isdown=false;
                  var  x=0;
                  var  y=300;

             function startstop(){   
                var elem = document.getElementById("start");
                if (elem.value==="Start")
                {
                    elem.value = "Stop";                        
                    var mycanvas=document.getElementById("Canvas");
                    var ctx=mycanvas.getContext('2d');
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.lineWidth=10;
                    ctx.strokeStyle="#ff0000";
                         while (isrun) {
                             if(isright){
                                 x=x++;
                             }
                             if(isup){
                                 y=y--;
                             }
                             if(isleft)
                             {
                                 x=x--;
                             }
                             if(isdown)
                             {
                                 y=y++;
                             }
```

In the above code though the value of isright is true but the value of x is not incrementing. Whats the problem

Comment: `x = x++` increments the value of `x` and then assigns the old value to `x`. Replace it with `x++`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are doing:

`x = x++`

Which only assigns `x = x`.

Just do

`x++` or `x = x+1`.

Same goes for all of those x/y assignments.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you assign the variables to the current value.
`x=x++;` is the same as `x=x` since `x++` is increased after the assignment.
You can either do `x=++x` to increment pre-assigning, or use just `x++`.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use [postfix increment/decrement operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Increment_and_decrement_operators) in an assignment - it does reassign the old value after having it updated! Do *either*

```
x = x+1; // x += 1; if you want
```

*or*

```
x++; // ++x; if you want
```

but not a mix.

Answer (score 0):

Write `x++;` instead of `x=x++;` x is incremented AFTER it has been assigned again, would have worked if you wrote `x=++x;` which of course is useless compared to simply `x++;`

Answer (score 0):

`++` only increments the value after being called once already, so if you have `x=0` and call `x++` then `x` still equals `0` but another `x++` will make x equal to `1`

Answer (score 0):

Because you use `x++`, which assign original `x` value first, then do incrementing without assigning value. So you alway have `x` value without any change. Try just `x++` or `x = x + 1`.